# Does anyone have any experience with no electric free power magnetic/repulsion powered motors

Tags: electrical

Does anyone have any experience with no electric free power magnetic/repulsion powered motors... What the power production possibilities maybe using rare earth N42 magnets .. if possible does the configuration of the magnets make a big difference or the shape of the magnets? Any and all feedback is welcome thanks.

Comment: What is 'free power'? Is this about perpetual motion machines?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's not about home improvement

Comment: "What the power production possibilities" - zero. "does the configuration of the magnets make a big difference" - no, there's no configuration which produces any power.

Comment: DON'T give any money to anyone trying to get you interested in free-energy magnet machines.

Comment: Sure, here's the most relevant research. https://www.tinaja.com/pseudo01.shtml.

Comment: Be sure to lubricate with a bit of cobra or anaconda oil. Python oil is inferior. ;^) ...and I hadn't even scrolled down to bobflux's answer when I wrote that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey but that's how they actually work - money flows from the gullible to the lying slimeballs. The perpetual motion machines eventually stop, but the scam has been running for *hundreds of years without stopping...* TANSTAAFL. Why, if the gullible stopped being gullible, the slimeballs would starve.

Comment: @Harper unfortunately Don Lancaster's site is also spreading pseudoscienc on that same page.  I'll raise it with him next ime I encouter him online.

Answer (score 6):

These things are snake oil, they don't work.

The great thing about magnets is they can be used to make low loss (low friction) spring powered mechanisms and couplings, which give the illusion that the movement will run forever... but it does not.